# Read text from website with arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to connect to a api and send a token key parameter to this server and return the text from that page.

For example I want to connect to this page :

`154.12.32.5:153?token=V6bFm8tVc8vFJMNQWUPY8Ag3dLzR6SKE`

I use Ethernet shild and Arduino uno.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is better explained with an example code:

```c
byte mac[] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };  // See sticker on your shield
byte ip[] = { 10, 0, 0, 177 };
byte server[] = { 154, 12, 32, 153 };  // IP from your question

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    delay(1000);  // wait a second so things are settled up ...

    if (client.connect(server, 153)) {  // Port from your question
        client.println("GET /?token=V6bFm8tVc8vFJMNQWUPY8Ag3dLzR6SKE HTTP/1.0");
        client.println();
    } else {
        // Connection failed code ...
    }
}

void loop()
{
    if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        // Do something with data ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working. `client.connect(server, 153)` return zero